# Objective C loading background Image for HTY360Player

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, 360-virtual-reality

I need to put a background image(before video buffering) for  HTY360Player that used for iOS 360 VR videos? 
Library used:  https://github.com/hanton/HTY360Player - Objective C

Comment: Vinod - I never worked in before `HTY360Player`  , but I seen property name is `playerControlBackgroundView` , go through once and update the view

Comment: where it locate(which file)? I have seen popoverBackgroundViewClass.
I have tried to put the image by putting an UIImage over the VideoPlayer.storyboard,  it worked.
but I could not see an area where the code get notification after the first sets of buffered input(video byte) received.